# How does binary-crossentropy decide the output

Tags: loss-functions, tensorflow, keras, cross-entropy

In Keras and tensorflow there is a loss function called binary crossentropy. When i use that the output neurons will only produce 0 and 1.

I see that in the code of keras, binary cross entropy is linked to `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` in tensorflow, and from there I assume it goes on to a c++ implementation.

I'd like to know how exactly is it decided whether it's 0 or 1. Is it simply rounding the output? I would like to know because I want create a custom loss function which will have weights and want to make sure I'm not introducing any bias.

Comment: this is definitely not off topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When i use that the output neurons will only produce 0 and 1.

Cross-entropy produces scores in $[0,\infty)$.

Examining the expression for cross-entropy should make this clear. For model parameters $\theta$, labels $y$ and predicted probabilities $p_i$, it is: 
$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta)= -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left[y_i \log(p_i) + (1-y_i)\log(1-p_i) \right]
$$
The function `sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_with_logits` is evaluating an equivalent expression that takes $\text{logit}(p_i)$ as inputs; this can be numerically nicer. (Working though the algebra of the above equation will provide you with the exact expression that the function `sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_with_logits` is evaluating.)

All of this to say: the output of the function `sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_with_logits` cannot possibly be binary for all outputs. Are you post-processing the probabilities or logits in some way? It is very common for people to employ argmax to coerce outcomes to be binary, 1-hot representations of class membership.

To answer the titular question, binary cross entropy loss doesn’t decide the outputs. It just scores “how wrong” the model is; larger values imply the model is “more wrong.”

Comment: Thanks. So the loss function is independent of the last layer? Or are there any criteria that need to be considered?

Comment: I actually wanted to know how the output of keras’ binary cross entropy is coerced to binary. Is it just using a threshold?

Comment: @Nickpick It doesn't coerce to binary. The only way it's producing outputs in $\{0, 1\}$ is if all inputs are either $e$ or $1$. The function just calls the corresponding TensorFlow function and returns the result. https://github.com/anayebi/keras-extra/blob/master/tensorflow_backend.py#L499 So the coercion to binary must happen somewhere else. You should find an appropriate forum for debugging Keras code and ask your code question there.

Comment: Ok makes sense. I found it now: `def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)` It simply rounds the value.

Comment: @Nickpick Yep, it looks like you were applying a post-processing to the network outputs!

Comment: I think what's important to note is that when the output neuron is sigmoid, the cross entropy loss function will output 0.

Comment: That is only the case for you because you’re doing nonstandard things. It is not true generally.